# Displaying the result of two grep commands in bash

Tags: bash, grep, find, output

I am trying to find the number of files in a directory with two different patterns in the filenames. I don't want the combined count, but display the combined result.

Command 1: `find | grep ".coded" | wc -l` | Output : `4533`

Command 2: `find | grep ".read" | wc -l` | Output: `654`

Output sought: `4533 | 654` in one line

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Quick but fragile hack: `printf "%s | %s\n" "$(find | grep ".coded" | wc -l)" "$(find | grep ".read" | wc -l)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the bash shell using `process substitution` and `pr`

```sh
pr -mts' | ' <(find | grep "\.coded" | wc -l) <(find | grep "\.read" | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `find`, you can use `-printf` to print whatever you want, for example a `c` for each file matching `.coded` and an "r" for each file matching `.read`, and then use awk to count how many of each you have:

```sh
find -type f \
    \( -name '*.coded*' -printf 'c\n' \) \
    -o \
    \( -name '*.read*' -printf 'r\n' \) \
    | awk '{ ++a[$0] } END{ printf "%d | %d\n", a["c"], a["r"] }'
```

---

By the way, your grep patterns match `Xcoded` and `Yread`, or really anything for your period; if it is a literal period, it has to be escaped, as in `'\.coded'` and `'\.read'`. Also, if your filenames contain linebreaks, your count is off.